# Removing "Edit with Pythonwin" from right click menu

Tags: windows, windows-7

Recently I installed pywin32, and decided that I didn't need it. So I uninstalled the application and packages using control panel, then removed the remaining folder. However, when I right clicked a `.py` file the `Edit with Pythonwin` was still there. I tried restarting my computer, but with no avail. I have googled it but found no answer. Is there some way I coud remove this option from the right click menu, or do I just have to deal with it? I use windows 7. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to delete the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.py
```

From PowerShell, you can use this

```
rd hklm:software/classes/.py
```

Comment: will that delete the "Edit with Idle" too?

Comment: Its the Gui that comes with python. I'll try what you recommendd, and if it delets The other button I'll just reinstall python.

Comment: Thank you. Your Idea didn't work, but it led me to find the solution.

Comment: @Anthony, if this helped you find the solution you should post what you did as a solution so that other people can be helped (just post your answer at the bottom)

Answer (score 2):

The more appropriate manner is to open with Regedit, head to the following path:

\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell

There, you need to remove the folder "Edit with PythonWin".

You can find this via the Find function.  You also may be able to remove the ability to run the Python file, or edit it with IDLE.

Comment: You may need to start RegEdit as admin.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). You can remove or disable shell-extensions with it.